# d3 v4 extent returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
var selectZoom = d3.brush().extent([[0, 0], [WIDTH, HEIGHT]])
                .on("brush",brush)
                .on("end", brushended);
 function brush(){
            var selection = d3.event.selection;
            console.log(selectZoom.extent()); // this prints function
            console.log(d3.extent(selectZoom)); // this prints [undefined,undefined]
        }
```

I am trying to set extent to **d3.js v4** brush. I tried two ways to access the extent. But both did not work.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log(selectZoom.extent().call());
```

Above statement worked for me.